# Parsring through multiple arrays in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a raw SQL output which contains a few arrays as well. I want to parse through these rows and iterate through the arrays in it.

I have written the below code:

```
     {% for row in in results %}
                 <li>Title : {{row.4}}</li>
                 <li>Description :{{ row.2}}</li>
                 {% for i in row.3|length|range %}
                      <li class="bs-callout">
                         <button id="{{row.3.forloop.counter0}}">{{row.4.forloop.counter0}}</button>
                         <span>{{row.5.forloop.counter0}}</span>
                     </li>
                  {% endfor%}
     {% endfor %}
```

Sample row :

```
['Col1','Col2',['txt1','txt2','txt3'],['txt1','txt2','txt3'],['txt1','txt2','txt3']]
```

In this case `row[5],row[6],row[7]` are arrays which contains 5-7 values.
For each row i want to print the title in `row[4]` and list array items as well.

Comment: By arrays you mean list right ?

Comment: Yes. It is returned by Postgres array_agg() function.

Comment: If i give {{row.5.0}},it gives the first value, but not accepting variables, tried {{row.5.i}} as well

Comment: But it's a django query object right? Can you share an example of how the outcome will look because its confusing as you have added row 5,6,7 in button but you want it in your title.

Comment: title is not an array, remaining objects are arrays. i ll edit the question and add more code

Comment: Updated code.Please check

Comment: you can wrap that code in block `with` for example `{% with row.4 as row_4_title %} {{ row_4_title }} {% endwith %}` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is the right way to do this. But this is the only thing which worked for me.

```
    {% for row in in results %}
       <li>Title : {{row.4}}</li>
       <li>Description :{{ row.2}}</li>
       {% for i in row.3|length|range %}
            <li class="bs-callout">
               <button id="{{row.3|getitem:i}}">{{row.4|getitem:i}}</button>
               <span>{{row.5|getitem:i}}</span>
            </li>
       {% endfor%}
    {% endfor %}
```

Where getitem is a custom filter.

```
@register.filter(name='getitem')
def get_item( list,offset ):
    return list[offset]
```